# inserting data into 2 tables with the same generated unique id using android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into two table with unique id being generated in Table1 and use the generate unique id in Table2.

Example:
I want to insert empl_no and empl_name into table 1 and table 2. After inserting the empl_no in Table1 it will auto-generate an id for that row. This id would need to be used to on Table2  to insert the empl_name.

```
Table 1
empl_id | empl_no
-----------------
1       | e00001

Table 2
empl_id | empl_name
-------------------
1       | Andy
```

What I have in mind is to insert empl_no into Table1 to then do a `select` to get the last row to retrieve the empl_id. Then use the empl_id to insert into Table2.

Is there a better to do this? It looks inefficient because each time to insert a data it will need to `select` from the Table just to get the generated unique id.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `empl_id` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in Table1 (optionally with `AUTOINCREMENT`, but it's better not to use it unless you explicitly need it) then you won't need the extra SELECT statement. The [`insert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) method will return its value.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that
>   column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID
>   using any of four different names, the original three names described
>   above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these
>   names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any
>   context.

And from the Android documentation:

> `public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`
>   Returns **the row ID of the newly inserted row**, or -1 if an error occurred.